# Vertical content slider - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I am trying to create vertical content slider using jQuery, I have tried creating but its not working. I am trying to change the slide on scroll, any navigation is not required, only the content have to changed on scroll.

[Here is the JSfiddle of my code](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/LoweLxpa/)

```js
function rotateImages(){
  $(".slide-item").animate({top: "-100%"}, 1000).delay(4000);
  $(".slide-item").animate({top: "200%"}, 1000).delay(4000);
}

$(".slider-wrapper").scroll(function() {
    rotateImages();
});
```

```css
.slider-wrapper {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
 background: #dedede;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}
.slide-item {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.item-one {
 top: 0;
}
.item-two {
 top: 100%
}
.slide-item > .img-block {
 float: left;
 width: 30%;
}
.slide-item > .img-block > img {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
.slide-item > .content-block {
 float: right;
 width: 70%;
 padding: 0 20px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-wrapper">
  <div class="slide-item item-one">
    <div class="img-block"><img src="https://camo.mybb.com/e01de90be6012adc1b1701dba899491a9348ae79/687474703a2f2f7777772e6a71756572797363726970742e6e65742f696d616765732f53696d706c6573742d526573706f6e736976652d6a51756572792d496d6167652d4c69676874626f782d506c7567696e2d73696d706c652d6c69676874626f782e6a7067"></div>
    <div class="content-block">
      <h1>Slider Heading 1</h1>
      <p>This is content related to slider. This is content related to slider.  This is content related to slider. This is content related to slider. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide-item item-two">
    <div class="img-block"><img src="https://camo.mybb.com/e01de90be6012adc1b1701dba899491a9348ae79/687474703a2f2f7777772e6a71756572797363726970742e6e65742f696d616765732f53696d706c6573742d526573706f6e736976652d6a51756572792d496d6167652d4c69676874626f782d506c7567696e2d73696d706c652d6c69676874626f782e6a7067"></div>
    <div class="content-block">
      <h1>Slider Heading 1</h1>
      <p>This is content related to slider. This is content related to slider.  This is content related to slider. This is content related to slider. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are attaching scroll to the wrong element. If you want scroll on slider-wrapper, then slider-wrapper should have overflow:scroll not overflow:hidden

Comment: Did you try `$(window).scroll(function(){rotateImages();});`

Comment: @karthick if I change the to overflow:scroll then scrolling will appear, that I don't want.

Comment: @locateganesh Yes I have tried with `window.scroll` as well but no luck

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [jquery-mousewheel](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel) because `scroll` event won't work until and unless there is scrollbar.

[**Fiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/LoweLxpa/3/)

```
$('.slider-wrapper').on('mousewheel', function(event) {
    console.log(event.deltaX, event.deltaY, event.deltaFactor);
    rotateImages();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think now I can achieve what I am looking for.